# Merkle Patricia Trie insertion, deletion and verification algorithms

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, algorithm

I've googled this for a while, but online guides mostly explain the addition part and do not give a comprehensive example.
What is the algorithm for such operations in Merkle Patricia Trie (insertion, deletion and verification).
What would a MPT proof look like? how would someone verify an MPT proof? Merkle trees are very easy to understand, but I'm having a hard time understanding steps required for these operations in Merkle Patricia Tries, specially verification of a proof.
An example without RLP encoding (if possible) is really appreciated.